# Create zip with PHP adding files from url

Tags: php, download, zip

I was wondering if the following is possible to do and with hope someone could potentially help me.

I would like to create a 'download zip' feature but when the individual clicks to download then the button fetches images from my external domain and then bundles them into a zip and then downloads it for them.

I have checked on how to do this and I can't find any good ways of grabbing the images and forcing them into a zip to download.

I was hoping someone could assist

Comment: You are describing quite a complex set of operations - you're question is not specific. What part of this are you having problems with? What have you tried?

Comment: I was more curious if there is such a way to download images from external domain into a zip file. I'm currently researchign possibilities

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
# define file array
$files = array(
    'https://www.google.com/images/logo.png',
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/project-logos/enwiki-2x.png',
);

# create new zip object
$zip = new ZipArchive();

# create a temp file & open it
$tmp_file = tempnam('.', '');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

# loop through each file
foreach ($files as $file) {
    # download file
    $download_file = file_get_contents($file);

    #add it to the zip
    $zip->addFromString(basename($file), $download_file);
}

# close zip
$zip->close();

# send the file to the browser as a download
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="my file.zip"');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($tmp_file);
unlink($tmp_file);
```

Note: This solution assumes you have `allow_url_fopen` enabled. Otherwise look into using cURL to download the file.

Comment: I receive the following "Windows cannot open the folder. The Compressed (zipped Folder 'C:\download.zip' is invalid

Comment: @DonaldSutherland see my edit. I did some stupid stuff with variable names.

Comment: Thanks for the code.. Anyway to also download folders/directories?

Comment: @Mr_Green, you can't really do that unless directory listing is enabled on the server, and even then you'd have to parse the HTML to get all the files in each folder.

Comment: @Prisoner please have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23052665/1577396).

Comment: @Prisoner thank you for the solution.

Comment: @Prisoner thank you sir for the solution, but how do we clear the temp file after the download progress?

Comment: You should add unlink($tmp_file) after you read the file so it doesn't clutter up hosting space

Comment: thanks buddy. worked like a charm...

Comment: Zip is downloaded successfully but when I extract it thrown `Archive is corrupted` error. I have tried with the same example without any change. Still facing the same issue

Comment: that's probably because `http://google.com/images/logo.png` no longer works. i've updated the examples to use https and fixed the 404 url.

Comment: Error "Windows cannot open the folder. The Compressed (zipped Folder 'C:\download.zip' is invalid" still going on

Comment: probably because the wikipedia image no longer works - i've updated the example

Answer (score 2):

I hope I didn't understand wrong.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

I haven't tried this, but it seems like what you're looking for.

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open('my_archive.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile($url, basename($url));
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```