# How to open the window multiple times and download the file in main window using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to download multiple files based on the user requirement. if the user want to download three files then i am repeating the for loop and opening the windows and downloading the files. but the first file is saving in main window afterwards the files are downloading in the  newly opened windows.

Code:

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
 {
   // this is the url where i am downloading the image
   var win = window.open("/Profiles/GetImage");
   window.close();
 }
```

How to download all the files at the first window

Comment: I didn't really get what's actually happening and what's wrong with this but shouldn't that be `win.close()` instead of `window.close()` ?

Comment: win.close also will be the same. I have already tried this

Answer (score 0):

You can put required files (images) in zip container on server-side. I don't think its possible to achieve it on client-side. User can download zip and unzip on desktop. It can done on server-side. For example in php you can use the below example for zip:

http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php

[Create zip with PHP adding files from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930049/create-zip-with-php-adding-files-from-url)

May be someone know the solution from client-side.

Comment: hi @Rajneesh071, how can i help ?