# How to Zip mutiple files using Zend Compress Filter?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zip

I have multiples files to be compressed into one unique file (zip), but it seems that it creates a new file everytime the loop restart, how do I do that? there is no enough documentation about this, here is my code:

```
        $file1 = "test1.xls";
        $files2 = array(
            "test2.xls", "test3.xls"
        );

        $filter = new Zend_Filter_Compress(array(
            'adapter' => 'Zip',
            'options' => array(
                'archive' => BASE_PATH .'/public/' . $this->configuracoes->get('media') . '/temp/zipped'.date('d-m-Y-H-i-s').'.zip'
            )
        ));

        $compress = $filter->filter($file1);
        foreach($files2 as $file){
            $compress = $filter->filter($file);
        }
```

This only result a zip with test3.xls inside.

Answer (score 2):

Worth looking at this link, seems to be the same answer where you open the zip, add files, then close it outside the loop.

[Create zip with PHP adding files from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930049/create-zip-with-php-adding-files-from-url)

Comment: not exactly what I wanted but I solved only by this way! I wish to use only zend compress, but it seems that zend doesn't have enough documentation about it. thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 2):

An old question but I found this looking for something similar.

You can pass a directory to the `filter` function and it will recursively add all files within that directory.

i.e

`$compress = $filter->filter('/path/to/directory/');`

Comment: I'm gonna test it when I go back to that project!

Comment: No it will not work. if we pass directory path, it will not recursively add all files. it will just put directory path as in text file