# Create a temporary folder to keep the files in structure and make it downloadable by compressing the folder

Tags: php, directory, compression, download, temporary-directory

In my project, I have some files related to items on **Server** as shown below:

```
Item-1  => file1.txt, file2.pdf and file3.doc
Item-2  => file4.pdf, file5.ppt
Item-3  => file6.txt, file7.docx and file8.ppt
....
```

I can get the above items by `$this->getAllItems()` and then loop through each item.

I am trying to compress all these files in a structured way. So, that the user can understand files belong to which items.

What I am trying to do is keep the files related to their respected items in a folder and wrap them in a "main" folder (*this should happen in a temporary path*) then Compress it and let the user download the compress folder. So, that the files will be in structured way as shown below:

```
main
   Item-1
      --> file1.txt
      --> file2.pdf
      --> file3.doc
   Item-2
      --> file4.pdf
      --> file5.ppt
   Item-3  
      --> file6.txt
      --> file7.docx
      --> file8.ppt
```

While searching here, I got a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13930314/1577396) which does compress the files (*but not folders*) in a temporary path and make the compressed folder available to download.

PS: **The compressing should happen for every download request by users**.

Comment: I don't know much about compressing and creating directories in temporary path.. so, I have no code but just a link to refer what I had tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is correct or not.. but this worked.

I modified the for loop part of the code which is available on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13930314/1577396).

```
# loop through each file
foreach($files as $file){

    # download file
    $download_file = file_get_contents($file);

    # Create a empty folder
    $zip->addEmptyDir($itemName);

    #add to the above created new folder in zip
    $zip->addFromString($itemName . '/' . basename($file), $download_file);

}
```

In the above code, `$itemName` is the item name which is fetched dynamically while looping in `$this->getAllItems()` as I had already mentioned in my post.

Please let me know if this is correct or not.